# Reference citation appear in list of figures and tables

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, citing

I am adding the reference in yje captions of Figures and Tables of my thesis. Reference is also appearing in the List of figures and list of tables at the start of the chapters. This is how I am citing in the captions of Figures and Tables.

`\caption{Graph showing global increase in herbicide resistance \protect \cite{heap2019international}.}`

I dont want it appear in the List of Figures and List of Tables. Is there any other approach to avoid that?

Comment: You can use the option argument of the `\caption` command to add a "short version"  that is used for the list of figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want citation call-outs to show up in the lists of figures and tables, don't include the `\cite` instructions in the optional arguments of `\caption`. E.g.,

```
\caption[Graph showing global increase in herbicide resistance.]{%
    Graph showing global increase in herbicide resistance %
    \protect{\cite{heap2019international}}.}
```